# Can i put anything in for x

Tags: python

I am learning how to code in python so I'm wondering if we can put anything in for x (key in this instance):

```
for key in prices:
  print key

  print "price: %s" % prices[key]

  print "stock: %s" % stock[key]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your post appears to be testable and quite easily. When you swapped out 'key' for 'x' or for 'skittle' or for 'wumpus', what did you find? When you swapped out 'key' for a number, like 3, what happened?

Comment: `x` is just a variable. It can be any valid python identifier.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  Unless you have a demonstrable problem with the code, it's not a good Stack Overflow question.  This is an archive of generally useful questions and solutions, not a tutorial resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can put any name there that you wish -- just as long as it's a valid variable name in Python. `key` is going to be the variable name for each item inside the `for` block.

Comment: Note that if the `key` in question doesn't exist in `stock` (or `stock` is the wrong type for that sort of key, e.g. `stock` is a sequence, `key` is neither `int` nor `slice`), you'll get exceptions.

Comment: Besides, key must be hasheable